# given two eigevectors with two eigenvalues and no A, compute Av?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I'm barely into eigenvalues and eigenvectors and the first problem from the first section tells me:

let A be a 3x3 matrix such that [-3,4,1] (column vector) is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue 3 and [6,-3,2] is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue 2. Now if v = [3,1,3], compute Av.

In this section we haven't gone over diagonalization, or anything besides finding stuff from a given particular matrix A., and the characterization equation. I tried writing out a general form and solving for each value by setting the two equations of each row to each other, but that seems impossible because they all have parameters. can someone tell me the simplest method to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\bar v= (3,1,3)=(6,-3,2)+(-3,4,1)$.

Since matrix multiplication is linear, $$A\bar v=A(6,-3,2) +A(-3,4,1)=2(6,-3,2)+3(-3,4,1)=(3,6,7)$$

Comment: now that I noticed those 2 eigenvectors add up to v, I can follow what you did. but I can't see how I can intuitively figure out that I can do that to begin with...

I know that Ax = 2(6,−3,2) = 3(−3,4,1)

but what exactly does it mean for matrix multiplication to be linear, and why are you allowed to make the calculation Av=A(6,−3,2)+A(−3,4,1)=2(6,−3,2)+3(−3,4,1) ?

Comment: What it means for matrix multiplication to be linear is that A(u+v)=Au+Av, i.e. if you multiply a matrix by a sum of vectors, you get the sum of the matrix multiplied by those vectors. And then I knew that A(6,-3,2)=2(6,-3,2) because (6,-3,2) is an eigenvector with eigenvalue 2, meaning that when I multiply A by (6,-3,2) I just get back 2(6,-3,2). The same goes for how I know that A(-3,4,1)=3(-3,4,1); it's an eigenvector with eigenvalue 3.

Comment: oh, I can see with lots of manipulation how you came up with that. what if I wanted to find A^2v?

Comment: If I were to say that A^2v=AAv=A(Av), would you see where to go from there? Keep in mind what it means for A to be linear, what it means for (6,-3,2) and (-3,4,1) to be eigenvectors, and that Av=2(6,-3,2)+3(-3,4,1).

Comment: I can see the options I have to manipulate AAv, but it seems as if i have to notice some type of hidden symetry somewhere to figure out the computed value. I have the same problem but with v = [0,5,4] and gathered that Av = A2u + Aw = [-6,18,1o], but can't seem to find the hidden symetry to compute A(Av) = A(A2u + Aw) = A(A2u) + A(Aw)

Comment: Letting u=(6,-3,2) and w=(-3,4,1), we have that Av=Au+Aw=2u+3w. So then A^2v=AAv=A(Av)=A(2u+3w) (since Av=2u+3w) =A(2u)+A(3w) (since A is linear) =2Au+3Aw (also since A linear) = 2(2u) + 3(3w) (since Au=2u and Aw=3w) =4u+9w

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean for $u = (6,-3, 2)$ to be an eigenvector with eigenvalue 2? That $Au = 2u$. Let $w = (-3,4,1)$. We know that $Aw = 3w$. Now importantly note that $v = u + w$. Can you compute $Av$ now?