# Linear Algebra - Multiplication involving eigenvalue/vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am re-doing a problem I missed on an exam and was wondering if someone could double check my work.

Consider the following vectors:
$$v_1 = (1,0,2), v_2 = (0,1,1),v = (2,1,5)$$
and the eigenvalues: 2 corresponding to $v_1$ and -1 corresponding to $v_2$

Find $Av$.

$Av = A(2v_1 + v_2) = 2Av_1 + Av_2 = 2(2)(1,0,2)-(0,1,1) = (4,-1,7)$

I found: [given two eigevectors with two eigenvalues and no A, compute Av?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044592/given-two-eigevectors-with-two-eigenvalues-and-no-a-compute-av) Which seems to agree with how I did it but I'm not sure why I was marked wrong? Thanks!

Edited to remove link

Comment: $v=2v_1+v_2$; use linearity.

Comment: Looks correct to me....

Comment: @MorganRodgers No,I'm just still trying to figure it all out!

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thanks, I'll have to run it by him. I was honestly just guessing on the exam and assumed I just did it wrong.